# C# Second button click resets changed items

Tags: c#, events, button, reset

First, I want the labels, links, and a different button to disappear and move when the question_group2 is first clicked. But after this, I want the items to reset after I click the same button again. This is my code. It does what I want at first, but I can't figure out how to reset at the second click. I will also have to keep functioning so a 3rd click would disappear everything, and a 4th would reset everything again. Please help. Thanks

```
    private bool button2Clicked = false;        

    private void question_group2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button2Clicked = true;
        if (button2Clicked == true)
        {
            this.question_group3_button.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(169, 284);
            this.question1_label.Visible = false;
            this.question2_label.Visible = false;
            this.question3_label.Visible = false;
            this.question4_label.Visible = false;

            this.question1_link.Visible = false;
            this.question2_link.Visible = false;
            this.question3_link.Visible = false;
            this.question4_link.Visible = false;

            this.add_question_link.Visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: btw, "if (button2Clicked == true)" will always be true because of the previous code line

Comment: Right now it looks like you are requesting for us to fix some bug but you never tell us the actual behavior, only the expected behavior. Could you please tell us what is happening currently?

Answer (score 3):

this.question1_label.Visible = !this.question1_label.Visible
Each click will set visibility to an opposite value

Comment: FWIW, I really love to see this logic tagged with `toggle` slapped onto the variable name.